# ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

### I am integrating an AD (JumpCloud) with the GCP. I followed the recommended procedure but when I get to the final step which is to give this command: gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml I get an error message in step 2 of the yaml file.
Error:
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Default service account 'idwall-security@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.]
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build ff6952d1-dbb2-4456-8956-9847ce3b365d completed with status "FAILURE"

I followed the procedure indicated in the same error message but I could not solve it.
Any idea?

Comment: It's complaining about service account idwall-security@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. Where are you setting this service account to be used?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.